# Android Firefox Native Libs

Tags: android, firefox, java-native-interface, firefox-addon, jsctypes

Does anyone know the native libraries (C) exposed by android to Firefox app? I plan to use js-ctypes but dont know the libs at my disposal. If you can please share those libs then I can look up the documentations and learn what all I can do. My goal is to take a native screenshot on Android.

Answer (score 1):

`window.JNI` baby. doneskis. can do whatever Firefox has permission to do on Android. Its jsctypes jni framework exposed by default to the window scope, very amazing.

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/modules/JNI.jsm

Im not sure which all c libs are available though, not sure how to list them out, just try it and see as you need it and if it doesnt work go JNI.

Copy paste jni example: example: https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-for-android-addons/blob/355f9a01464a0794c1084e8fdbab92c58503f49a/snippets/jni.js#L23-L44